# Is there a default way to have cmake run make with an appropriate -jX argument?

Tags: makefile, cmake

If I have a cmake build tree configured with the -G"Unix Makefiles" option, I understand that I can run

```
cmake --build . -- -j10
```

to pass the `-j10` option to make but is there a way to tell `cmake --build` to do this by default (probably when I run the initial cmake)?  I'd like to avoid having to write shell scripts that call `cmake --build` with arguments that depend on the generator.

Right now I'm looking at a bunch of scripts that figure out arguments to cmake, and they hardcoded calls to `make -j$NCPUS`; I'd like to improve the scripts to make them generator-agnostic, but would really rather not have a bunch of code that looks like `if GENERATOR == Unix Makefiles; then DO A THING else DO SOMETHING ELSE.`

I did find https://blog.kitware.com/cmake-building-with-all-your-cores/, but that just talks about how to hand-code the flags for each generator.

Comment: Use Ninja instead of Makefiles. Then you have no need to add such magic.

Comment: That's not a practical suggestion.  The point of cmake is that it can build multiple systems, not that it's a Ninja generator.

Comment: I see your point, but there is no way to achieve what you want. You could manipulate CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM which has its downsides, too.

Comment: See [CMake Issue #16951: CMake: Enable parallel builds by default when using `--build` command line option](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/16951). I'm [currently working on this](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/merge_requests/1282) and my plan is to add `CMAKE_PARALLEL_LEVEL` variable to be able to define the number of cores on project level.

Comment: Ok, I've done the necessary changes (see [CMake Merge Request #1962](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/merge_requests/1962)). I would be happy if you could do some testing and add feedback to the merge request.